# In conducting likelihood ratio tests, why do statisticians normally neglect to write out the constant cutoff point, $\lambda(x) < \text{constant}$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Suppose that we are doing a likelihood ratio test. We normally wish to find for a family of pdf's $f_\theta(x)$, for the test of hypothesis $H_0: \theta \in \Theta_0$ and $H_1: \theta \in \Theta$:

$$
\lambda(x) = \frac{\sup_{\theta\in\Theta_0}L(\theta\mid X)}{\sup_{\theta\in\Theta}L(\theta\mid X)}
$$

In most books I have seen, they usually find this, then say that a Uniformly Most Powerful test is of the form:

$$
\lambda(x) < \text{constant}
$$

They normally neglect to display that constant. I am wondering why this is so. Doesn't the cutoff point depend on that constant?

Comment: Well, the constant will depend on a bunch of things - the significance level you're testing at, the actual form of the pdfs at hand, and so on.

Comment: This is related to you other question about the likelihood ratio test for a one-parameter beta distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cutoff point *is* the "constant". Normally one finds a monotone function $g$ for which the distribution of $g(\lambda(X))$ is understood and tabulated (and in this era "tabulated" should be taken to mean on-the-shelf software deals with it). Thus if, for example, if $g$ is a decreasing function and $g(\lambda(X))\sim t_n,$ and one is testing at level $\alpha$, then one finds for which value of $c$ one has $\Pr(t_n >c) = \alpha,$ and then one rejects the null hypothesis if $g(\lambda(X))>c.$ The value of $c$ of course depends on $\alpha$.

I suspect I could say more if you gave a concrete example.

Comment: Got it, so basically you're saying that the function $g$ carries all the constants over to the other side of the inequality so that I am left with a part that is stochastic and has a nice distribution to exploit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "carries all the constants over to the other side".  But $g$ is a monotone function, so $\lambda(x) < c$ implies either $g(\lambda(x)) < g(c)$ or $g(\lambda(x)) > g(c). \qquad$